# Can't open sdf file

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

SQL Compact 4 is installed on my computer but I can't open the sdf file from the solution explorer.The icon is a blank document not the yellow cylinder

Comment: Do you get any message while opening sdf file?

Comment: Please see this similar question: [Opening .sdf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375118/how-to-open-sdf-files) This will answer your question. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

There are currently no built-in tools in Visual Studio for working with SQL Server Compact 4.0 database files. (they will come with Vs2010 SP1). You can use my Visual Studio add-in http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com or one of the other tools listed here: http://erikej.blogspot.com/2009/04/sql-compact-3rd-party-tools.html

You can download sql ce through web api just follow this link

[visual-studio-tools-for-sql-serverl](http://erikej.blogspot.com/2010/12/visual-studio-tools-for-sql-server.html)

Please check above link.